# Criteria to see if a battery was over-discharged in the case of Li-ion cells and NiMH batteries

Tags: lithium-ion, measurement, nimh

Consider a Li-ion pouch battery from an RC model. Is there any reliable way to determine by measurement if the battery was in a over-discharged state in the past. (In particular I am looking for method that works, if the battery was charged, maybe multiple times, after the over-discharge occurred).

Does internal resistance measurement lead to a reliable criterion?

Same question for NiMH batteries, where the answer may be different because of the different chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instrument to measure DC resistance (not AC impedance at 1 kHz), then, yes, you can tell whether a Li-ion battery is degraded compared to a brand-new, identical Li-ion battery. However, that degradation can be due to many causes, not just over-discharge.

If you have the instruments to measure the self-discharge rate (it will take a month to detect it), then, yes, you can tell it that rate is excessive compared to a brand-new, identical Li-ion battery. While that degradation can be due to many causes, the most likely cause of a high self-discharge rate is over-discharge.